# ASP.NET Identity vs custom implementation, which one to use?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm a junior full stack and I'm working on a big SPA (for one man) project, as a challenge and demo of what I have learned and I have 3 questions:

1. `Is generally ASP.NET Identity used` in companies for medium/big projects or they usually go with custom implementation ?
2. I wonder if `it's worth using ASP.NET Identity` for users and roles management `or` is better to `create custom logic` for users/roles to I guess learn more and have more control.
3. If `I'll continue developing with identity`, will be bad if I use it only for users and roles management, as I saw that it has authentication API too, but I use `OAUTH2`, setting token was like fast and it's working. So should I try to use Identity as much as I can in authentication too to `explain the use` of this framework over custom implementation ?

You can answer only to first question because other two are too subjective. Thanks!

Comment: the problem with this questions that any answer will include "it depends", no one answer or one case that apply on all, but may be someone give you some advices here.

Comment: @Amr Elgarhy, setting up token was fast with owin and oauth2. Much more difficulty I had with Identity customization, as I inherited it's classes and also was using DI and had some errors.

Comment: may be it worth showing some code issues you got to be able to help better.

Comment: @Amr Elgarhy, I can but it will be out of the context of my question. Now I try to decide if I should manually write users and roles api and create required tables with entity framework, leave code as it is and not using identity for anything else than users/roles/claims table management through Identity API, or make full use of Identity like Visual Studio default mvc template does.

Comment: Yes I understand your point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ASP.NET Identity is very customizable, you can take the best from both worlds.

In my company we use custom implementation of `IUserStore` giving us the flexibility to persist user info the way we wanted. We don't use Entity Framework, for example, which is the default data access used by ASP.NET Identity.

In our case the tables are different and they better match to actual user data for our application (read business objects).

The password hashing/verification process is different also, etc.

You just need to pass an instance of your custom `IUserStore` to `ApplicationUserManager` and you are good to go.

My personal opinion is: go with ASP.NET Identity and replace just the parts you need.

EDIT: 
You can also implement all of those too

```
IUserStore<,>
IUserLoginStore<,>
IUserClaimStore<,>
IUserRoleStore<,>
IUserPasswordStore<,>
IUserEmailStore<,>
IUserLockoutStore<,>
IUserTwoFactorStore<,>
IQueryableUserStore<,>
```

We use it for authentication too. Have in mind that this is tested and will be updated. Is is also well documented and any new devs that are jumping on the project have a greater chance to know what is happening. If you go with a completely custom solution you'll have to maintain that and try to keep it updated with the latest trends/stuff.

Hope this helps to make a better decision.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer @Mihail Shishkov . I'm trying to respect coding standards and principles. Do you use Identity just for user/roles management or for authentication too ?

Comment: I've edited my answer :)